# Modify link to access user profile

Tags: wordpress, widget

I wish to change wordpress link code from below in order to access user profile not user posts.

```
$output .= '<a href="'. $author_posts_url.'" rel="author" class="fn">'. $the_author.'</a></span>';
```

in order to access

```
<a href="<?php echo $userpro->permalink($user_id); ?>" class="userpro-flat-btn userpro-transition"><?php _e('View Profile','userpro'); ?></a>
```

best regards

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking as it's currently written. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: i have one wordpress plugin wich slist recent post. Above title has author and date. What i need is to change first link $output... in order to go in author profile page not to author post listing